# In Bigquery, How can I convert Struct of Struct of String to Columns

Tags: struct, google-bigquery, nested

So, In the table, there are 3 columns as per Image , 3rd one is Record(Struct), conntaing 2 structs old and new. Inside those structs there are columns and values.

I can access each final column by this -change.old.name , But I want to convert them as normal columns and create another taable with that ?

tried unnest but doesn't work as it's not array.

[Data structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwcNd.png)

**UPDATE :**

Finally got it sorted. Should select and convert all columns by selecting all of the nested data and set the alias as how we want or replace dot with an underscore. Then create a table with that.

```
    create table abc 
as 
select 
ID
,Created_on
,Change.old.add as Change_old_add
,Change.old.name as Change_old_name
,Change.old.count_people as Change_old_count_people
,Change.new.add as Change_new_add
,Change.new.name as Change_new_name
,Change.new.count_people as Change_new_count_people
FROM `project.Table`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Finally got it sorted, The elements of struct can be called as Table.old and specific nested data can be accessed as Table.old.name.

Comment: UPDATE : 
Finally got it sorted. Should select and convert all columns by selecting all of the nested data and set the alias as how we want or replace dot with an underscore. Then create a table with that.  

create table abc 
as 
select 
ID
,Created_on
,Change.old.add as Change_old_add
,Change.old.name as Change_old_name
,Change.old.count_people as Change_old_count_people
,Change.new.add as Change_new_add
,Change.new.name as Change_new_name
,Change.new.count_people as Change_new_count_people
FROM `project.Table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it sorted. Should select and convert all columns by selecting all of the nested data and set the alias as how we want or replace dot with an underscore. Then create a table with that.

```
 create table abc 
as 
select 
ID
,Created_on
,Change.old.add as Change_old_add
,Change.old.name as Change_old_name
,Change.old.count_people as Change_old_count_people
,Change.new.add as Change_new_add
,Change.new.name as Change_new_name
,Change.new.count_people as Change_new_count_people
FROM `project.Table`
```